# How to assign an image to a specific Wordpress-page

Tags: wordpress

I want to use something like *Feature Image* in Wordpress 5.2.2 so I can optionally use that image as a thumbnail whn that page gets displayed in a parent category page.

Actually though I don't see that option anywhere on my page, neither in the document nor in the blocks sidebar. Is it something I need to activate and if so - where?

Just to explain what I understand with Feature image:
A page may get assigned 1 image that can be then used as e.g. a visual excerpt for that page and must not be displayed on the page itself.

Comment: This is a theme-related issue. Maybe this can help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40613/how-can-i-add-a-featured-image-to-a-page.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the featured image won't show up if it isn't checked in the screen options tab.

[image: The 'Screen Options' tab will be displayed just underneath the top navigation bar in the admin area]

Once checked you'll then be fine to add your featured image to the page/post.